# select gradient colours in plot() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, colors, arguments

Hello I am trying to get a plot that looks like the attached picture however I would like to change the colours so that they form a gradient ( the three levels of the plotted variables are actually three points in a continuum). So for example it would be best if the red line is orange, the blue line is going towards yellow and the red is yellow [image]

The code I used for these plots is the following:

```
 p13 <-plot(pred,ci.style="ribbon",alpha = 0.2) + theme_clean() +    
geom_line(size=0.1) + labs(x="Time", y="Task", title = "Plot Title",  
subtitle = "Subtitle") + 
theme_clean(base_size = 10)  + theme(
plot.background = element_blank(),
panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
panel.border = element_blank()) +  theme(legend.position = "bottom")  
par(mar=c(5,6,4,1)+.1) 
p13
```

Comment: I am trying to solve it but this does not seem a correct ggplot code it is missing the aesthetics argument, what is on the x axis and on the y axis? these have to be defined. does this code work on your pc?

Answer (score 1):

You are using ggeffects, makes sense to include it in your question. When you call `plot()` on a ggeffect object, it returns a ggplot object, so you just specify the colors and fill using scale_*_manual, there are a lot of tutorials for example something like [this](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-colors-how-to-change-colors-automatically-and-manually).

And for colors, you can check out the [palettes](https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/sites/default/files/2020-04/colorPaletteCheatsheet.pdf) you like, i use a yellow-orange.

Using iris dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggeffects)
library(RColorBrewer)

iris$grp  = sample(c("A","B"),nrow(iris),replace=TRUE)
fit = lm(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length+Species+grp,data=iris)
pred = ggpredict(fit,terms=c("Petal.Length","Species","grp"))
```

Then plot:

```
plot(pred,ci.style="ribbon",alpha = 0.2)+
scale_color_manual(values=brewer.pal(3,"YlOrRd"))+
scale_fill_manual(values=brewer.pal(3,"YlOrRd"))
```

[image]